# How do I declare a type parameter that derives from a specific class?

Tags: f#

How do I declare a type parameter that derives from a specific class?

**I'm attempting to do the following:**

```
let registerTable (T:EntityData) (client:IEasyMobileServiceClient) =
    client.RegisterTable<T>(); client
```

**However, this results in the following error:**

> Error     The type 'T' is not defined

**Here's the signature for *RegisterTable*:**

```
abstract member RegisterTable : unit -> unit when 'A :> EntityData
```

Answer (score 2):

Given *EntityData* is the type my generic needs to derive from:

```
let registerTable<'T when 'T :> EntityData> (client:IEasyMobileServiceClient) =
    client.RegisterTable<'T>(); client
```

The caller can look like this:

```
registerTable<TodoItem>
```